# seo for dynamic urls in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, sitemap, react-helmet

I am creating 100s of links using `<links>` but I am not able to do SEO for it

I am trying to create sitemaps for these links but as its dynamic, I cannot manually create a sitemap file

this the link

```
 <Link to={{pathname: `query/${itm._id}`, query: { id: itm._id },}} >
  <Alert className="question13">
  <h6>{itm.Name}</h6>
  </Alert>
</Link>
```

the corresponding route for the link is here

```
 <Route
exact
path="/Query/:catId"
render={(props) => (
<Query {...props} sign={userNAme} hide={SignIn} />
)}
/>
```

I have used helmet so that I can render dynamically each page title and description

```
                <Helmet>
                  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                  <title> {itm.Name}</title>
                  <meta name="description" content={itm.Name} />
                  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
                  <link rel="canonical" href={itm.Name} />
                </Helmet>
```

https://wixten.com/

this is the website I am trying to do SEO for. As you can see if you open site and add a question a new url gets generated I don't know how to do SEO for each of that

Comment: ?? in my react app??

Comment: Sitemaps have almost nothing to do with SEO.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).   They can get Googlebot to come crawl all your URLs but they don't usually entice search engines to index pages nor do they help rankings.

Comment: Sitemaps should never be manually generated.  You would typically have a program that runs daily to generate your sitemap by listing all your dynamic pages from your database.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with react, does that `<Link>` tag get rendered as a normal `<a href=...>` link in the DOM?  If so you may not need to do anything else for Google to find your pages.